# How to create timeout on external secured website

Tags: javascript, session, ssl, timeout, kiosk

**The Program**

I currently have built a web based Kiosk system "all client side" that has 5 selections to choose from.  4 of those options are links to vendors that we use containing logins for banking products.

**My Goal**

I would like to create a timeout for when someone clicks on an link and visits a website that I dont have control over. When this timeout occurs, it returns to the homepage of the kiosk.  I dont care if its the current window, child window or an iframe.  Being that the level of usage by multiple people is high, I need to protect against people not logging out of the product they are.

**My Current Problems**

I tried to retain control over a child window but microsoft has removed the focus ability from child windows.
Even though I am trying to keep this clientside, I am open to server side functionality but I dont have that sort of control being the site being visited is external to my control.
Iframes I wouldnt mind using, but becuase its a secured external website it presents a error prompt and security risk.

**Kiosk Hosting Options**

I currently host this kiosk and the files in a SharePoint environment but could change it to be on its own iis server if need be.  Even though I am not a huge fan of IE it is what we use as our business standard so I need to have this usable within that browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout to reset the SRC of an Iframe, no problem there.

The problem is that you have no way of knowing whether the user is actively using the external site. Your timer may reset the location while they're in the middle of doing something. The Same Origin Policy prevents the parent page from sniffing what's going on in the Iframe.

Comment: So it can be done with the iframe but like you mention there is no way for me to tell if there is activity within?  If not then an ifram would be no good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load the external site in an iFrame and in the parent, define the timeout.  This example will redirect in 3 seconds :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

t=setTimeout(function(){
    window.location = "http://YourHomepage";
},3000);

</script>
</head>

<iframe src="http://YourVendor"></iframe>
```

Obviously, you will need to size the iFrame, correct the links and change the timeout to something more suitable.

Comment: Thank you,, can you tell if there is actvity within the iframe to reset the timer?